# Regex pattern - Exclude part of string

Tags: regex, groovy, regex-lookarounds

I have a number of strings where I'd like to just pull out an episode name from a string if it exists. Here are a few examples

```
The Case of the Case
(#1.1)
Cameron Diaz/Mark Ronson & Bruno Mars (#40.7)
Cameron Diaz/Smashing Pumpkins (#24.1)
Candice Bergen/Cher (#13.5)
```

So a full line consists of "episode name (#s.e)" where s is series number and e is episode number, but as you can see sometimes there can be no series/episode number and sometimes there can be no episode name.

I have the following regex

```
(.+ )(?! \(\#[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\))
```

So group 1 should pull out the episode name, the above pattern seems to work ok for all cases apart from `The Case of the Case`, instead of the full episode name it only pulls out `The Case of the` any ideas?

To clarify the matches we should get from the above are

```
The Case of the Case
Cameron Diaz/Mark Ronson & Bruno Mars
Cameron Diaz/Smashing Pumpkins
Candice Bergen/Cher
```

Comment: Is removing the last parenthesized part an option? See [`\s*\(#\d+\.\d+\)$`](https://regex101.com/r/RYYRPO/1). BTW, what is the regex engine you are using? See a [fancy PCRE regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p8HrdC/2).

Comment: using regexpal, hmmm I think I see what your saying match the second part then base the start index of that match to pull out the first bit?

Comment: Where will the regex be used? The best regex solution always takes into account the code it will be used in. Python, Java?

Comment: Yes it should be. As for where it's used, reading lines from a file and dissecting the string with regex in Groovy (there's more than just this to each line)

Comment: I might misunderstand your requirements. If you read line by line and  you need to get `The Case of the Case` because the `(#1.1)` follows it immediately on the next line, then `(.+)(?=\s+\(#[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\))` won't work. You will have to read the whole file in.

Comment: Is **"The Case of the Case"** only a match because **"(#1.1)"** on the following line?

Comment: Sorry it's confusing because I've only given you part of a line, the second line is for a different programme to the first. It just so happens that line two doesn't have the episode name as part of it.

Comment: So, is [removing the `(#x.x)` part at the end of the string](http://ideone.com/hlKWFy) is an option? If it is not at the end, you still may use `s.replaceFirst(/\s+\(#\d+\.\d+\).*/, "")`

Comment: Yes, yes it is as I'll extract the (#x.x) separately, I literally just want the episode name if it exists

Comment: Or you can do `^([^(]+)(?: \(\#\d+\.\d+\))?` if I am understanding correctly.

Comment: @PaulStatham: So, shall I post my solution?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah sure

Comment: Posted with explanations.

Comment: @PaulStatham I added a simple solution that does this.

Comment: @PaulStatham when you say *"there's more than just this to each line"* does that mean that the **only** way to identify a title is by the presence of a (#N.N) ??   **OR**  Are you saying that **each line** will be a title, **BUT**, ***some*** lines will only have a (#N.N), and ***others*** will only have a title -- but ***either way*** - *** every line refers to an "episode" ?

Comment: @PaulStatham because if every line in your file refers to an episode, you could use `^[^\(\)]*\b`.  If the text match has to be based on the presence of a (#N.N) after it, then use this awesome one: `^(.*?)(?=\n?\()(.*)$`  -  See my answer for more details

Answer (score 2):

You can use a positive lookahead in your regex instead of a negative lookahead as this:

```
(.+)(?=\s+\(#[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\))
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PCh2fJ/2)

`\s` matches any whitespace including newline. Lookahead expression will assert presence of `"\s(#s.e)"` ahead of episode name.

Comment: This I like very much :)

Comment: And if the demo input is a bit different, it will not work. See https://regex101.com/r/r1OTTy/1. Also, this approach is resource consuming as there is a lot of backtracking here.

Comment: Sure, we can use quantifier in front of `\s`  to make it match multiple whitespaces.

Comment: That's not a valid episode name as per the question since it is not followed by `(#s.e)`

Comment: Ok, I see that we understood the input and requirements differently. However, it won't work if OP is reading a file line by line.

Comment: This is only matching **The Case of the Case** because **(#1.1)** is on the following line. I understood that the `\(#[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\)` is optional.

Answer (score 2):

## EDIT - Based on the comments:

**This Regex:**

```
^(.*?)(?=\n?\()(.*)$
```

Ensures that:

- `\1` **returns only a name** (even if there's no (#n.n)
- `\2` **returns only (#n.n)** (even if there's no name)
- Text that doesn't fit this pattern is skipped.

**Example (clickable demo):**

[image]

[image]

---

## OR

## Based on this:

> I literally just want the episode name if it exists

This is drastically simpler:

```
^[^\(\)]*\b
```

- This also works with POSIX 1003.2 extended Regex (i.e. `egrep` & busybox router compatible)

**[Click for demo](https://regex101.com/r/F2yOZV/1)**

[image: Click for demo]

---

## Or

## Alternative with second group

```
^([^\(\W].[^\n]*?(?=$| [$\(]))\s*?(\(.[^\(]*?\))?$
```

Has the added flexibility that it `\2` will give you the (#s.e) code.

**[Click for demo](https://regex101.com/r/aqCACX/1)**

[image: Click for demo]

Answer (score 2):

Since you are reading line by line, and you just want the `(#<NUM}.<NUM>)` part removed from the lines, the simplest solution is to *replace* with the following regex:

```
def s = "Cameron Diaz/Mark Ronson & Bruno Mars (#40.7)"
print(s.replaceFirst(/\s+\(#\d+\.\d+\)$/, ""))
// => Cameron Diaz/Mark Ronson & Bruno Mars
```

If there is no match, the string will come back unmodified. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HRVDsb/1).

The `$` matches the end of string. If the episode details may appear in a non-final position in the string, remove the anchor.

**Details**:

- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `\(` - a literal `(`
- `#`  - a literal `#`
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `\)` - a literal `)`
- `$` -  end of string anchor

Comment: This matches the opposite of what OP wanted ?? ... and requires a specific function (in java of all things)

Comment: @hmedia1: Exactly, because this regex is for *replacing*. Did you read my answer or just jump at the regex?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
^([^(]+)(?: \(\#\d+\.\d+\))?
```

[Demo & Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/GMIzUg/1/)